# How do I bind a MouseClick on a button the same way I did with the Return button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my XAML code I have defined a button:

```
<Button 
    Content="Enter" 
    FontSize="25" 
    Width="250" 
    Height="50" 
    Command="{Binding ReadyFirst}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding EnableButton}"
    >
    <Button.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding 
            Key="Return" 
            Command="{Binding ValidateInsert}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EnterButton}"
            />
        </Button.InputBindings>
    </Button>
```

This button is bound to the Return Key so that I can do magic stuff with it in the ViewModel.

Now I also want the user to be able to click on this button and perform the same action as the return button, but somehow this cannot be achieved the same way as the Return button.

Here is an example of my ViewModel just in case..

```
public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ValidateInsert { 
    get { 
        return new DelegateCommand(OnValidateInsert, CanExecuteRequest); 
    } 
}

private void OnValidateInsert()
{
    m_DVM_Pos = m_DVM_Pos.Replace(',', '.');
    ConvertedDVM_Pos = Convert.ToDouble(m_DVM_Pos);
    EnableLastButton = true;

    m_CanExecuteTestContinue = false;
    FireReady();
    m_CanExecuteTestContinue = true;
}
```

So, is it possible for the left mouse button to use the same binding as the Return button on my keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another binding:

```
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="ValidateInsert" />
```

So it becomes:

```
<Button Content="Enter" FontSize="25" Width="250" Height="50" Command="{Binding ReadyFirst}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnableButton}">
    <Button.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding ValidateInsert}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EnterButton}"/>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="ValidateInsert" />
    </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

Comment: I did not expect that one to work because there was no autocomplete for the "Gesture" code, while there was autocomplete for the "Key" code. But it did work, so thank you =)

Comment: Check [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseaction(v=vs.110).aspx) for your auto complete options

Comment: And if you wish to do something like a Control+Click that is also possible: `Gesture="Control+LeftClick"`